# How to send an email using Python

Tags: python

I made a simple keylogger in C++. I want to send an email with the input the keylogger made using Python. I know you can do it with C++ but I want to use Python.

Comment: What have you tried?  You can invoke external programs like sendmail, or you could look at smtplib as potential starting points.

Comment: Moreover, it appears you are building some sort of malware, we are not going to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You I hope that your keylogger is for educational purposes only. Anyway, 
here is a simple way to send one e-mail using Python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = ['to@todomain.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Here, you have placed a basic e-mail in message, using a triple quote, taking care to format the headers correctly. An e-mail requires a From, To, and Subject header, separated from the body of the e-mail with a blank line.

To send the mail you use smtpObj to connect to the SMTP server on the local machine and then use the sendmail method along with the message, the from address, and the destination address as parameters (even though the from and to addresses are within the e-mail itself, these aren't always used to route mail).

If you're not running an SMTP server on your local machine, you can use smtplib client to communicate with a remote SMTP server. Unless you're using a webmail service (such as Hotmail or Yahoo! Mail), your e-mail provider will have provided you with outgoing mail server details that you can supply them, as follows:

```
smtplib.SMTP('mail.your-domain.com', 25)
```

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm